# Skew GradientBackground Whitespace

Tags: css

It's hard to see but on the INSIDE of the Border, left and right side only of the skewed rectangle, there is whitespace which is only there if I have a gradient background

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMfXC.jpg

my css:

```
padding: 50px 0;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 0;
border: 4px solid #717171;
transform: skewX(352deg);
box-shadow: -5px 10px 10px 0px #0b0b0b2b;
cursor: pointer;
background: rgb(41,41,41);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(41,41,41,1) 0%, rgba(59,59,59,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(41,41,41,1) 0%, rgba(59,59,59,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(41,41,41,1) 0%, rgba(59,59,59,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#292929",endColorstr="#3b3b3b",GradientType=1);
```

Any CSS magicians could help me with the whitespace on the inside? as I'd like to have the rectangle skewed with a gradient. But they don't work together so well. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some html code snippet as well?

Comment: I only have a <h2> centred inside of a <div>, the styling above is for the div